# sending instant messages through python (msn)

Tags: python, twisted, msn

ok I am well aware there are many other questions about this, but I have been searching and have yet to find a solid proper answer that doesnt revolve around jabber or something worse. (no offense to jabber users, just I don't want all the extras that come with it)

I currently have msnp and twisted.words, I simply want to send and receive messages, have read many examples that have failed to work, and msnp is poorly documented.

My preference is msnp as it requires much less code, I'm not looking for something complicated.

Using this code I can login, and view my friends that are online (can't send them messages though.):

```
import msnp
import time, threading



msn = msnp.Session()
msn.login('XXXXXXX@hotmail.com', 'XXXXXX')
msn.sync_friend_list()

class MSN_Thread(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        msn.start_chat("XXXXXXX@hotmail.com") #this does not work
        while True:
            msn.process()
            time.sleep(1)



start_msn = MSN_Thread()
start_msn.start()
```

I hope I have been clear enough, its pretty late and my head is not in a clear state after all this msn frustration.

edit: since it seems msnp is extremely outdated could anyone recommend with simple examples on how I could achieve this?
Don't need anything fancy that requires other accounts.

Comment: this is probably due to the fact that msnp's last update was in 2004. I think that a few years ago MSN switched protocols MSN protocol 11 and I think they're on Protocol 13 now.  I could be horribly wrong though

Comment: could potentially explain this: raise Error(int(resp.cmd), protocol.errors[resp.cmd])
NameError: global name 'Error' is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is also xmpp which is used for gmail.

Comment: This is what I ended up using, even though I found it months ago.
Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a library abandoned in 2004 so i'm not sure if msnp could still be used to talk on MSN.
Anyway i would try with:

```
while True:
     msn.process(chats = True)
     time.sleep(1)
```

using the contact id and not the email address.

```
contacts = msn.friend_list.get_friends()
contact_id = contacts.get_passport_id()
```

Your code just start the chat without sending anything; you need to add the code to send message.
Have a look to `send_message` method in [this](http://msnp.sourceforge.net/tutorial.html#a2_5) tutorial.

Comment: not sure what thats supposed to do, has not allowed me to send a message to another account yet.

Comment: @Code according to the tutorial, the chats = True option tells msn to process commands for all currently active chat sessions.

Comment: @system not quite sure what you mean there, but I changed [msn.start_chat("Joe")], now I'm getting a "global name 'Error' is not defined" I guess thats something, care to elaborate?
edit: and yes, I did use the name of the contact "Joe" instead of the email address

Comment: @system, is this what you mean?contact_id = friend.get_passport_id(), contact_id = contacts.get_passport_id()
I keep getting errors on the last one. I'm putting them in the while loop if it means anything.

Comment: @system is any of this working for you? my account logs in but nothing else happens. edit: also contacts is an empty list, contact_id shows up as nothing

Comment: @code Are you aware that you are not sending any text message with your code?

Comment: @system oh dear, told you it was late (only just occured to me). using help(msn.start_chat) there seems to be no way of adding a message to the code, or am I not looking hard enough? Just tested again and surely enough it won't take anymore arguments.

Comment: I have already tried that code, but for some reason it doesnt do anything, not even log in. I did change the login details too.

Answer (score 0):

It  looks like [papyon](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/papyon) is a maintained fork of the pymsn library, and is currently used by telepathy-butterfly and amsn2.

> papyon is an MSN client library, that tries to abstract the MSN protocol gory details. It is a fork of the unmaintained pymsn MSN library. papyon uses the GLib main event loop to process the network events in an asynchronous manner.